# While i am executing the DB2 Java class and i am getting db2 error

Tags: db2

While i am executing the DB2 Java class and i am getting the below error.

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-4742,
>   SQLSTATE=560D5, SQLERRMC=6, DRIVER=4.24.92

Thanks,
Rasheed SK

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions and suggestions in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n4742.html)?
Specifically for the -4742 sqlcode.

Answer (score 0):

your table is not added idaa check your table from idaa db